# Laravel 7 "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Validator' not found"

Tags: php, laravel

A few days ago I started learning laravel 7.
I bought a course on udemy.
I got to the part where the real registry system went and started to rewrite the code like in the video, but when I do it I get an `error`!

```
Error Message: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Validator' not found"
```

**I've been trying to fix this for hours, and I'm not doing well**

**AccountController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function getcreate(){
        return view('account.create');
    }

    public function postcreate(){
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), 
        array(
            'email'  =>      'required|max:50|email|unique:users',
            'username' =>    'required|max:20|min:3|unique:users',
            'password' =>    'required|min:6',
            'repeat_pass' => 'required|same:password'   
        ));

        if($validator->fails()){
            die('ERROR');
        }
        else{
            die('Cool');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems you are using very old tutorial (if you installed Laravel 7 and that you showed is not some inherited code base).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to import `validator` namespace

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

then instead of `Input` you could use `request()->all()` helper function

so it will be like this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function getcreate(){
        return view('account.create');
    }

    public function postcreate(){
        $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), 
        array(
            'email'  =>      'required|max:50|email|unique:users',
            'username' =>    'required|max:20|min:3|unique:users',
            'password' =>    'required|min:6',
            'repeat_pass' => 'required|same:password'   
        ));

        if($validator->fails()){
            die('ERROR');
        }
        else{
            die('Cool');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any example of writing
request-> all () I think I'll do it

Comment: Thank you so much I was able to fix this!

Comment: @Nik33__ you are welcome :), if it helps accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import the `Validator` class from it's correct namespace which is `Illuminate\Support\Facades`. So goes with `Input` class. Best way I can suggest is to add these in `aliases` section in `config\app.php` like below:

```
 'aliases' => [
     // other imports
     'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
     'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
 ]
```

Now, you can simply `use` them in your controller like below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Validator;
use Input;


class AccountController extends Controller
{
 // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Validator` namespace in your controller at top like:

```
use Validator;
```